# @ResponseBody unexpected format

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC controller for my plain-old-xml web service with the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/trade/{tradeId}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getTrade(@PathVariable final String tradeId) {
    return tradeService.getTrade(tradeId).getXml();
}
```

Which kinda works, the output in my browser is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Trade id="foo"/>
```

But if I "view source" then the actual output is

```
<string>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;Trade ...
```

This is not what I wanted, obviously. How to get the actual XML returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you try to write XML directly, but the xml converters assume you are giving them objects and they marshal it to XML.

You need to register the [`StringHttpMessageConverter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/StringHttpMessageConverter.html) before xml converters. Like:

```
<bean
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
            <property name="messageConverters">
                <list>
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter" />
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter" />
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.http.converter.feed.RssChannelHttpMessageConverter" />
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter" />
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter" />
           </list>
         </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: ah, had an XStreamMarshaller registered. Which is now redundant, as not using XStream, but had forgotten the marshaller. I removed all the marshallers and it seems to be good now. Cheers.